# How to execute a JavaScript function after making wicket label as visible?

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I have a JavaScript function which will split the text inside of the `<span>` and will generate 3 `<span>` for each part.

For the first time page loads with labelA visible and labelB not visible.
the user will do an action in order to tell that he wants to see labelB and hide the Label A.

After the user clicks the submit button to show labelB the page will render again and the JS will split the text again now for labelB.

All fine until here but when I navigate to another page and then I try to come back (using wicket buttons not browsers one) as per "bundle" is still selected the labelA must not be visible.

While the page is loading just for few seconds the labelA appears, the JavaScript do the job and after render completes the LabelA is now hidden and the LabelB is visible but the text is not in 3 parts.

In the JS file I am using window.onload in order to execute the function after the dom renders but it's not working. After render completes wicket hides labelA and shows labelB but JS function was executed before labelB appears then labelB text is only in one `<span>`.

Is there any way to execute the JavaScript function after label is visible?

Before executing the Javascript

```
<span wicket:id="labelA">some text here</span>
```

in this case labelB will be hidden

after executing the Javascript

```
<span class="style1">some</span>
<span class="style2>text</span>
<span class="style3>here</span
```

```java
//text value comes from DB
Label labelA = new Label("labelA", text){
  @Override
  protected void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response)
  {adding javascript into header}
};
if(!text.equals("simple")
{
  labelA.setVisible(false);
}
add(labelA);
Label labelB = new Label("labelB", text){
  @Override
  protected void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response)
  {adding javascript reference}
};
if(!text.equals("bundle")
{
  labelB.setVisible(false);
}
add(labelB);
```

Comment: I edited your question to make the <span>s in the text visible. Not sure what to do about the Java code though. Your text doesn't mention Java at all.

Comment: What JavaScript do you use? Please show us! I see you use Wicket's `#setVisible(boolean)` but then you say that the label is initially shown and some JS hides it. I'd expect the first label to be already hidden and the second to be split.

Comment: Try setting the .setVisible(bool) in the onConfigure of the New Label() { @Override onConfigure() }, that way wicket does the show/hide